Edge Gap in Shadow Catcher Material Masking Blender Eevee
so I'm trying to render an object with shadow, since eevee doesnt have shadow catcher, (blender 36.2) I use "material shadow catcher", then separate the render in two layer (the object & shadow), the problem I encounter shows that there is a gap between the object and the shadow (I use photoshop to merge those layer), anyone know how to fix this? thx


